# How to reload the old view if im close the webView?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, subview

I have added an webView to my app, its get opened by pressing a button. 
Above this webView I added an button that should close the webView.

If Im pressing the button the webView closed like it should do but its show only a Blackscreen, i guess i have to reload the ViewController.
How could i do that?

```
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView

     let button = ButtonDesign(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
      button.addTarget(webView, action: #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
     self.view.addSubview(button)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you set the webview as the vc's view , but you need to add it as a subview with `addSubview`

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
// set a non-zero frame 
webView = WKWebView(frame:view.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.uiDelegate = self
view.addSubview(webView)  // add it here
view.backgroundColor = .red  // change view's color

let button = ButtonDesign(frame: CGRect(x: 320, y: 50, width: 50, height: 50))
button.setTitle("X", for: .normal)
button.addTarget(webView, action: #selector(webView.removeFromSuperview), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(button)
```

When remove do

```
webView.removeFromSuperview()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `webview` as `subview`.

You are actually replacing the `self.view` to web view.

```
view = webView <--- ITS' WRONG: viewcontroller's view is replaced by web view
```

Replace the above line of code with following...

```
view.addSubview(webView)
```

The final code should be like...

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.uiDelegate = self
view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate back you should dismiss or pop ViewController.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```